# OpenGL multisampling doesn't work?

Tags: opengl, antialiasing, fragment-shader, multisampling

I called glEnable with GL_MULTISAMPLE and used "sample in vec4 color" as the input vector in my fragment shader, yet multisampling is still off.
What am I doing wrong? Is there any parts I'm missing?

p.s. I'm reading the official OpenGL programming guide (ver 4.3).

Edit: some code:

the fragment shader is as follows:

```
#version 430
sample in vec4 color;
out vec4 outputColor;

void main()
{
    outputColor = color;
}
```

And in my application I call glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE).
Right after that I render a simple cube that rotates and it clearly isn't antialiased.

Comment: You should better clarify your question. Also add the code you tried.

Comment: You're code does not fit to what you described: shader in ... has to be sample in ...

Comment: Yeah my bad, I use sample in and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

You must select a pixelformat for your window that actually supports multisampling. Without that, enabling multisampling in OpenGL has no effect.

Comment: I use freeglut. How do I select the pixel format for me window? I already call  glutInitDisplayMode( ... | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE ).

Comment: See also *Render-to-Window* section in [Multisampling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling).